# Is this a correct way to think about recursivity in programming? (example)

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion

I've been trying to learn what recursion in programming is, and I need someone to confirm whether I have thruly understood what it is.

The way I'm trying to think about it is through collision-detection between objects.

Let's say we have a function. The function is called when it's certain that a collision has occured, and it's called with a list of objects to determine which object collided, and with what object it collided with. It does this by first confirming whether the first object in the list collided with any of the other objects. If true, the function returns the objects in the list that collided. If false, the function calls itself with a shortened list that excludes the first object, and then repeats the proccess to determine whether it was the next object in the list that collided.

This is a finite recursive function because if the desired conditions aren't met, it calls itself with a shorter and shorter list to until it deductively meets the desired conditions. This is in contrast to a potentially infinite recursive function, where, for example, the list it calls itself with is not shortened, but the order of the list is randomized.

So... is this correct? Or is this just another example of iteration?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I was fortunate enough to get three VERY good answers by  @rici, @Evan and @Jack. They all gave me valuable insight on this, in both technical and practical terms from different perspectives. Thank you!

Comment: The simplest definition of recursion is a function that is defined *in terms of itself*. If the question is asking "when to use recursion vs iteration", then that is something different.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any iteration can be expressed recursively. (And, with auxiliary data structures, vice versa, but not so easily.)

I would say that you are *thinking* iteratively. That's not a bad thing; I don't say it to criticise. Simply, your explanation is of the form "Do this and then do that and continue until you reach the end".

Recursion is a slightly different way of thinking. I have some problem, and it's not obvious how to solve it. But I observe that if I knew the answer to a simpler problem, I could easily solve the problem at hand. And, moreover, there are some *very* simple problems which I can solve directly.

The recursive solution is based on using a simpler (smaller, fewer, whatever) problem to solve the problem at hand. How do I find out which pairs of objects in a set of objects collide?

1. If the set has fewer than 2 elements, there are no pairs. That's the simplest problem, and it has an obvious solution: the empty set.
2. Otherwise, I select some object. All colliding pairs either include this object, or they don't. So that gives me two subproblems.
3. The set of collisions which don't involve the selected object is obviously the same problem which I started with, but with a smaller set. So I've replaced this part of the problem with a smaller problem. That's one recursion.
4. But I also need the set of objects which the selected object collides with (which might be an empty set). That's a simpler problem, because now one element of each pair is known. I can solve that problem recursively as well:

   - I need the set of pairs which include the object X and a set S of objects.

     1. If the set is empty, there are no pairs. Simple.
     2. Otherwise, I choose some element from the set. Then I find all the collisions between X and the rest of the set (a simpler but otherwise identical problem).
     3. If there is a collision between X and the selected element, I add that to the set I just found.
     4. Then I return the set.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you have the right mindset of how recursion works.

Practically speaking, **you would not want to use recursion for an instance such as the one you described above**. Reasons being is that every recursive call adds to the stack (which is finite in size), and recursive calls are expensive on the processor, with enough objects you are going to run into some serious bottle-necking on a large application. 
With enough recursive calls, you would result with a stack overflow, which is exactly what you would get in "infinite recursion". You never want something to infinitely recurse; it goes against the fundamental principal of recursion.

Recursion works on two defining characteristics:

1. A **base case** can be defined: It is possible to eventually reach 0 or 1 depending on your necessity
2. A **general case** can be defined: The general case is continually called, reducing the problem set until your base case is reached.

Once you have defined both cases, you can define a recursive solution.
The point of recursion is to take a very large and difficult-to-solve problem and continually break it down until it's easy to work with.

***Once our base case is reached***, the methods "recurse-out". This means they bounce backwards, back into the function that called it, bringing all the data from the functions below it!
It is at this point that our operations actually occur.

Once the original function is reached, we have our final result.

For example, let's say you want the summation of the first 3 integers. The first recursive call is passed the number 3.

```
    public factorial(num) {
      //Base case
      if (num == 1) {
         return 1;
      }
      //General case
      return  num + factorial(num-1);
    }
```

Walking through the function calls:

```
factorial(3); //Initial function call

//Becomes..

factorial(1) + factorial(2) + factorial(3) = returned value
```

This gives us a result of 6!

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems to me like iterative programming, but your function is simply calling itself as a way of continuing its comparisons. That is simply re-tasking your function to be able to call itself with a smaller list.

In my experience, a recursive function has more potential to branch out into multiple 'threads' (so to speak), and is used to process information the same way the hierarchy in a company works for delegation; The boss hands a contract down to the managers, who divide up the work and hand it to their respective staff, the staff get it done, and had it back to the managers, who report back to the boss.

The best example of a recursive function is one that iterates through all files on a file system. ( I will do this in pseudo code because it works in all languages).

```
function find_all_files (directory_name)
{
    - Check the given directory name for sub-directories within it
    - for each sub-directory
        find_all_files(directory_name + subdirectory_name)

    - Check the given directory for files
    - Do your processing of the filename; it is located at directory_name + filename

}
```

You use the function by calling it with a directory path as the parameter. The first thing it does is, for each subdirectory, it generates a value of the actual path to the subdirectory and uses it as a value to call find_all_files() with. As long as there are sub-directories in the given directory, it will keep calling itself.

Now, when the function reaches a directory that contains only files, it is allowed to proceed to the part where it process the files. Once done that, it exits, and returns to the previous instance of itself that is iterating through directories.

It continues to process directories and files until it has completed all iterations and returns to the main program flow where you called the original instance of find_all_files in the first place.

One additional note: Sometimes global variables can be handy with recursive functions. If your function is merely searching for the first occurrence of something, you can set an "exit" variable as a flag to "stop what you are doing now!". You simply add checks for the flag's status during any iterations you have going on inside the function (as in the example, the iteration through all the sub-directories). Then, when the flag is set, your function just exits. Since the flag is global, all generations of the function will exit and return to the main flow.